# how to concatenate multiple columns dynamically where column names are stored as delimited string Pandas

Tags: pandas, split, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate the columns dynamically. The column names are stored as delimited strings in column 'merge':

```py
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame({'prodName': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3'],
               'mfr': ['m1', 'm2', 'm3'],
               'segment': ['s1','s2','s3'],
       'brand': ['b1','b2','b3'],
       'merge': ['mfr!segment','mfr!brand','segment!brand']})
 df
```

`df` output:

```
     prodName   mfr  segment   brand           merge
 0        p1     m1       s1      b1     mfr!segment  
 1        p2     m2       s2      b2       mfr!brand
 2        p3     m3       s3      b3   segment!brand
```

`df` expected output:

```
     prodName   mfr  segment   brand           merge   new_col
 0        p1     m1       s1      b1     mfr!segment      m1_s1    
 1        p2     m2       s2      b2       mfr!brand      m2_b2
 2        p3     m3       s3      b3   segment!brand      s3_b3
```

I have tried using `pd.factorise` but it expects 1D data.
I have achieved desired output by iterating over rows

```py
 for index, row in df:
     colstomerge=[col for col in row["merge"].lower().split("!")]
     df['new_col']=df.loc[:,colstomerge].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

I am looking for a more elegant and optimal solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following - assign a temporary column with list of columns to be joined and merge using .join. It should work for any number of columns separated by '!' in the 'merge' column

```
df["new_col"] = df.assign(cols=df["merge"].str.split("\!")).apply(
    lambda row: "_".join(row[row["cols"]].fillna("")), axis=1
)

print(df)
```

`df` output:

```
  prodName mfr segment brand          merge new_col
0       p1  m1      s1    b1    mfr!segment   m1_s1
1       p2  m2      s2    b2      mfr!brand   m2_b2
2       p3  m3      s3    b3  segment!brand   s3_b3
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still having some trouble dealing with nans, like imagine if 'mfr' is nan for one of the row

Comment: You could do `fillna("")` in the lambda as edited in the answer, then np.nan will appear as empty e.g. _b2 if m2 was np.nan, if you want some other string such as "nan", just do fillna("nan")

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply()` and **define a function** that does the concatenation depending on the `merge` column:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define function to merge strings depending on merge col
def merger(x):
    a, b = x['merge'].split('!')
    return x[a] + "_" + x[b]

df = pd.DataFrame({'prodName': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3'],
              'mfr': ['m1', 'm2', 'm3'],
              'segment': ['s1','s2','s3'],
      'brand': ['b1','b2','b3'],
      'merge': ['mfr!segment','mfr!brand','segment!brand']})

# Apply function to rows
df['new_col'] = df.apply(merger, axis=1)
```

`df` output:

```
  prodName mfr segment brand          merge new_col
0       p1  m1      s1    b1    mfr!segment   m1_s1
1       p2  m2      s2    b2      mfr!brand   m2_b2
2       p3  m3      s3    b3  segment!brand   s3_b3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I actually have to merge more than 2 columns in my real dataset